# List formatting in HTML

Tags: html, css

[The Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVwQX.jpg)

[The HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT3bd.png)

[The CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1LuG.png)

(I don't really understand how to post the code here - sorry)

I am a beginner in HTML and StackOverflow. Today is my first time using StackOverflow. I had a question about formatting my lists in HTML. I want to have 2 lists be next to each other but in the center of the screen. I have 2 lists side-by-side but can't figure out a way to get it into the center. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="what">
    <ul style="font-size: 125%; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-weight: bold; ">
      <li>Sterling Silver Jewelry</li>
      <li>Copper Jewelry</li>
      <li>Beaded Jewelry</li>
      <li>Bone Jewelry</li>
      <li>Home Furnishings</li>
      <li>Flutes</li>
      <li>Music</li>
      <li>Books</li>
      <li>Pendleton Items</li>
  </ul>

  <ul style="font-size: 125%; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-weight: bold;">
      <li>Lamps</li>
      <li>Rugs/Placemats</li>
      <li>T-Shirts</li>
      <li>Candle Holders</li>
      <li>Teas</li>
      <li>Soaps</li>
      <li>Balms</li>
      <li>And much more</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 90% there; you just need to use `justify-content` to position the contents of your flex container along the horizontal-axis. `align-items` is for positioning on the vertical-axis (note: both of these rules are reversed if you switch your `flex-direction` to `column`, btw).

```css
.listContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="listContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>Sterling Silver Jewelry</li>
    <li>Copper Jewelry</li>
    <li>Beaded Jewelry</li>
    <li>Bone Jewelry</li>
    <li>Home Furnishings</li>
    <li>Flutes</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li>Books</li>
    <li>Pendleton Items</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Lamps</li>
    <li>Rugs/Placemats</li>
    <li> T-Shirts</li>
    <li>Candle</li>
    <li>Holders</li>
    <li>Teas</li>
    <li>Soaps</li>
    <li>Balms</li>
    <li>And much more</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd recommend reading up a little more on [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to get your confidence up when using it -- it has a lot of useful properties!

Comment: Hi, I just realized that my comment didn't post but I appreciate your reply and your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing them in a 2 column grid, such as the following:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <b>List 1:</b><br />
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1a</li>
      <li>Item 1b</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="rightx">
    <b>List 2:</b><br />
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2a</li>
      <li>Item 2b</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following css:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

You can see this in action with this JSFiddle is here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/op46Lfds/2/)

Edit: I'm new to stackoverflow in respect to how some things work, such as their built in runnable code snippets.  So this edit is try it out, and to provide a stackoverflow-based runnable content instead of going through JSFiddle.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <b>List 1:</b><br />
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1a</li>
      <li>Item 1b</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="rightx">
    <b>List 2:</b><br />
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2a</li>
      <li>Item 2b</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your reply but I was looking for something a bit different from your response and someone else ended up figuring it out. I really do appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for the note, and you're more than welcome.  There can be so many ways to do the same thing, that sometimes having a few options to work with can help you find the best solution.  So glad you did find something that works perfectly for your needs.